# How to send the image icon to its original place in listview after dropping it onto the view port?

Tags: qt, listview, qt5

I have a listview , which represent view icons. I want to do drag and drop of these icons onto the view port, I am able to drag and also am also able to retrieve the item number of listview but on drop event I am not able to release the icon.

Please anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.